# Error with e.PaintCells() not painting cells when overriding DataGridViewRow.OnRowPrePaint

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to fully control the painting of DataGridViewRows in a derived DataGridView by overriding the `OnRowPrePaint` method. To test the approach I am trying to paint all cells contents and background using the `EventArgs` paint methods e.g. `e.PaintCells()` or `e.PaintCellsBackground()` and then setting `EventArgs.Handled = true` to prevent any of the other paint methods from firing.

My code so far is:

```
    protected override void OnRowPrePaint(DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.RowBounds);
        }            

        e.PaintCellsBackground(e.RowBounds, true);
        e.PaintCells(e.RowBounds, e.PaintParts);

        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

I was expecting this to colour the row blue and then the `e.PaintCellsBackground()` and `e.PaintCells()` methods to paint the cells ontop of the blue background however I am just presented with blue rows with nothing else painted. The remarks on the MSDN article on `PaintCellsBackground` reads

> Use the PaintCellsBackground method when you draw the DataGridViewRow and its cells' contents yourself. If you manually paint the entire row and its cells' contents, set the HandledEventArgs.Handled property to true. When HandledEventArgs.Handled is true, the CellPainting and RowPostPaint events do not occur.

Which leads me to believe I should be able to do what I'm hoping?

Comment: I did a lot fo my cell colouring with row.Cells[n].Style.BackColor, and row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor.. etc

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Please reword the question and say what the problem is and what is expected result. Also share more effective code if there is a problem in code.

Comment: thank you for the feedback @reza I've updated my question

Comment: I tested the code, It draws also cells. Probably the problem is something else which we can't reproduce using this code. I created a `MyDataGridView` containing your code and set a `DataTable` with 2 columns and some rows as `DataSource` of the grid. The result was not beautiful, but cells were drawn. [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XChPm.png) is the result of my test.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the feedback, I cannot find the article but I read that you can set `e.handled = true` in `OnCellPainting` and `OnRowPostPaint` and handle all of the painting in `OnRowPrePaint` but I didn't appreciate that this meant **ALL** of the painting.

When you call any of the paint methods in `OnRowPrePaint`, `OnCellPainting` is also called and appears to handle the actual painting where as I had it disabled in my code expecting the `e.PaintCells()` method to do the painting.

**Example 1**

```
class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    protected override void OnRowPrePaint(DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.PaintCells(e.RowBounds, e.PaintParts);
        e.PaintHeader(true);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    protected override void OnCellPainting(DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCellPainting(e);
    }
}
```

In this example `OnRowPrePaint` paints the cells and headers and `OnCellPainting` fires to do the painting and the `DataGridView` paints as expected

**Example 2**

```
class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    protected override void OnRowPrePaint(DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.PaintCells(e.RowBounds, e.PaintParts);
        e.PaintHeader(true);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    protected override void OnCellPainting(DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

In this example `OnRowPrePaint` attempts to paint the cells and headers but when `OnCellPainting` is triggered Handled is set to true and nothing gets painted, resulting in a blank `DataGridView`

**Example 3**

```
class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    protected override void OnRowPrePaint(DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    protected override void OnCellPainting(DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCellPainting(e);
    }
}
```

In this final example `OnRowPrePaint` is handled without any of the paint methods being called and `OnCellPaint` is never fired to paint any of the row contents, the column headers are painted but nothing else.

The key was understanding how `OnRowPrePaint`, `OnCellPainting` and `OnRowPostPaint` tie together.

Comment: *The key was understanding how OnRowPrePaint, OnCellPainting and OnRowPostPaint tie together.* This is why you should post *More effective code* because *the problem is something else which we can't reproduce using this code.*. When you ask a question, asking [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is really important :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei thank you for the link, the article is really useful. It's not until I started breaking the problem down into a presentable manner (which I should have done first) that I wrapped my head around the problem! I need to learn to take a step back and not dive straight in all the time :D